# Uso dell'aggettivo "inevaso"

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Nel libro *Nuovo Contatto C1. Corso di lingua e civiltà italiana per stranieri* (Loescher Editore, Torino) di R. Bozzone Costa, M. Piantoni, E. Scaramelli e C. Ghezzi, ho letto un testo adattato da un articolo di Alessandra Retico apparso a *La Repubblica*, a cui appartiene questo brano:

> Destreggiarsi è il motto. Le donne lo sanno bene, da sempre e sempre più spesso adesso. Sono *multitasking*: l'89,2 per cento delle signore (contro il 77,1 degli uomini) ha l'abitudine alle gincane quotidiane, anche si poi si lamenta di giorni sempre più corti e di cose che ogni volte rimangono **inevase**. Che sia una bolletta, un saluto ai genitori o un po' di sonno.

La mia domanda è sull'uso dell'aggettivo "inevaso" che si trova in questo passaggio. Non lo conoscevo, quindi l'ho cercato in alcuni dizionari. Ecco la definizione che ho trovato sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/inevaso/):

> agg. [comp. di *in*-2 e *evaso* (nel sign. 2)]. – Nel linguaggio burocr., di lettera o domanda che non ha avuto risposta, o di pratica e sim. a cui non s’è dato corso: *Si accumula la posta ‘Inevasa’ sul tavolo. Parrebbe Che io sia stato molto importante Ma non l’ho fatto apposta (Montale)*.

L'ho cercato in altri dizionari e tutti coincidono su questo fatto: si tratta di un vocabolo del linguaggio burocratico. Tuttavia, il testo che ho riportato non è burocratico e, per questa ragione, vi chiedo: è usuale questo uso di inevaso con il significato di "cosa non fatta"?

Comment: Forse è "giorni sempre più corti"?

Comment: Hai ragione, @Benedetta! Faccio la correzione.

Comment: @Charo - nell' esempio che tu citi, inevaso viene chiaramente usato in senso figurato. Inevaso significa "non eseguito, non fatto". L'uso figurato può potenzialmente essere usato in ogni  o,ta che  vuoi esprimere quel concetto. Quindi se vuoi sapere se è comune usare inevaso riferendosi ad un saluto ai genitori, la risposta è no, ma il significato è comunque chiaro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In effetti, questo aggettivo è usato prevalentemente nel linguaggio burocratico; non è raro, però, trovare termini burocratici usati nel linguaggio giornalistico. Nel caso di questo articolo, penso che l'aggettivo voglia stabilire un parallelo tra le pratiche burocratiche e le molte cose diverse che le donne si trovano a dover fare ogni giorno. Normalmente, per dire che una cosa non è stata fatta non si usa "inevaso", ma perifrasi.